# Find Co-located points in single layer

Tags: qgis, buffer, spatial-query

I have a layer (currently the source is a csv file) with 130,000 points.  Many of these points are co-located in a building room.

How can I identify points that are within a small distance of another point on the same layer?  Basically I want to add a buffer around each points and then only display points where the buffer is touching another.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! What is the overall process and result you're expecting? You mention 'co-located' in the title - will you try to reduce points to a limited set of clusters?

Comment: Not exactly.  I just want to highlight/segregate the points that are co-located.  They will still remain as separate points.

Comment: Lets try >> Vector>Geoprocessing>Buffer with dissolve function and next spatial query with points and dissolved buffer.

Comment: I am doing something wrong because even after converting to a shapefile my buffer is just a giant polygon covering the entire screen.

Comment: Could you post an image of a section of the points, and highlight examples of how you will decide if they are co-located? You have a better chance of getting an answer (or solving it yourself) if you give more information about the exact steps and decisions you'd like to make about these points.

Comment: Maybe your buffer is too high. We don't know what means "Co-located" for you. Give us a screen and show what exactly you need.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the CRS you use for your points layer is measured in meters. You can change the CRS by right-clicking the points layer and selecting the `Save As...` option. Then:

1. Apply a **buffer** with a specified distance. I made an example:

   [image: Points and buffer layer]
2. **Duplicate** the buffer layer (*right-click buffer layer > Duplicate*):

   [image: Duplicated buffer layer]
3. Use the **Spatial Query** plugin.

   - Installed from *Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins*
   - Accessed from *Vector > Spatial Query*

     Select the relevant layers as shown in the image (the *overlaps* function worked for me) then click the button which to Create layer with list items**:

   [image: Spatial Query]
4. The output should show the buffers which touch each other:

[image: Buffer output]

5. To select only the points inside those buffers, you can run another **Spatial Query** using the original points layer to find the intersection with the overlapping buffer layer:

   [image: Another spatial query]

   You can then close the window to see all the selected points inside those touching buffers (shown as yellow points):

   [image: Selected points]

   There are a number of ways to extract those points inside the buffers such as creating another layer with the **Spatial Query**, **Intersect**, Clip tools etc.

Comment: @DoDo1975 - Most welcome buddy! Glad it was helpful :)